# How do i change custom view package name while that custom view xml file in the AAR file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar

i have aar file that contains drawable, layout and java file. One of xml file that contains Custom view and its class name is as per old project. so when i used in my new project then i get error of (i showed below)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.techreco.arcmenu.lib.AnimatedPathViewGroup" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.pc28.arcmultiple-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.pc28.arcmultiple-2, /system/lib]]

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.techreco.arcmenu.lib.AnimatedPathViewGroup
```

so how do i solve this?

My current project package name: com.example.pc28.arcmultiple
and Custom view that is inside AAR file and its package name i cannot access. That custom view is

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<com.techreco.arcmenu.lib.AnimatedPathViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/animated_path"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

<com.techreco.arcmenu.lib.ArcLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     /> </merge>
```

Comment: Your class names are probably getting obfuscated, add to your progurad.pro file  `-keep class com.techreco.arcmenu.** { *; }`

Comment: Probably. i try it and give answer to you. thank you

Comment: Also check that you have set `minifyEnabled  true`, because a proguard file only gets processed in that case

Comment: ok. i get it. Thanks @Radix

Comment: Actually, i did not change that custom view package name while creating a aar file. so that xml file cannot find that class.